# mod_rewrite to nginx rewrite rules

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have converted most of my Apache HTTPd mod_rewrite rules over to nginx's HttpRewrite module (which calls PHP-FPM via FastCGI on every dynamic request). Simple rules which are defined by hard locations work fine:

```
location = /favicon.ico { rewrite ^(.*)$ /_core/frontend.php?type=ico&file=include__favicon last; }
```

I am still having trouble with regular expressions, which are parsed in mod_rewrite like this (note that I am accepting trailing slashes within the rules, as well as appending the query string to every request):

#### mod_rewrite

```
# File handler
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\.([a-z]+)$ _core/frontend.php?type=$2&file=$1 [QSA,L]

# Page handler
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)$   _core/frontend.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/$ _core/frontend.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)$   _core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/$ _core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)$   _core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/$ _core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
```

I have come up with the following server configuration for the site, but I am met with unmatched rules after parsing a request (eg; `GET /user/auth`):

#### attempted nginx rewrite

```
location / {
    # File handler
    rewrite ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\.([a-z]+)?(.*)$                                /_core/frontend.php?type=$2&file=$1&$3 break;

    # Page handler
    rewrite ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)(\/*)?(.*)$                                     /_core/frontend.php?route=$1&$2        break;
    rewrite ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)(\/*)?(.*)$                   /_core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2&$3     break;
    rewrite ^([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)\/([a-z0-9-_,+=]+)(\/*)?(.*)$ /_core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2/$3&$4  break;
}
```

**What would you suggest for dealing with my File Handler (which is just `filename.ext`), and my Page Handler (which is a unique route request with up to 3 properties defined by a forward slash)?**

As I haven't gotten a response from this yet, I am also unsure if this will override my PHP parser which is defined with `location ~ \.php {}`, which is included before these rewrite rules.

Bonus points if I can solve the parsing issues without the need to use a new rule for each number of route properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing the following rules:

**File Handler**

```
location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ { include /web/_config/php.conf; rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /_core/frontend.php?type=$2&file=$1 last; }
```

The file handler grabs the name and extension and writes it into type={ext}&file={name}.

**Page Handler**

```
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)$ { include /web/_config/php.conf; rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)$ /_core/frontend.php?route=$1 last; }
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ { include /web/_config/php.conf; rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ /_core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2 last; }
location ~ ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ { include /web/_config/php.conf; rewrite ^/([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ /_core/frontend.php?route=$1/$2/$3 last; }
```

The page handler (which in this case handles up to 3 "directories") grabs the string between each separator(/), does a regex-validation and writes it as a query string.

The main difference between this and my original configuration was that each entry has its own location handler, with the `last` rule it processes it on the first match, so performance should be slightly better.

I also discovered that nginx appends query strings by default, so that regex isn't required, another performance improvement.

Note that `/web/_config/php.conf` is simply a FastCGI pass-through configuration, and the one shipped with nginx (usually `/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf`) should work fine. Note that if you're dealing exclusively with PHP, you don't need to define this in each rule, just prepend them with the include.

Hope this helps.